# How to get return value of two days price in one SQL statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have Table like this

```
create table #tmp(dt Date, price float)

insert into #tmp values('01-Jan-2013', 55.60)
insert into #tmp values('02-Jan-2013', 50.22)
insert into #tmp values('03-Jan-2013', 52.00)
insert into #tmp values('04-Jan-2013', 55.90)
insert into #tmp values('05-Jan-2013', 60.60)

select * from #tmp order by dt
drop table #tmp
```

I want to get return value of two days price in one SQL statement. Calculation is simple, for example if I want to Calculate Return value of Date 02-Jan-2013 is: price value of  02-Jan-2013 divide by price value of 01-Jan-2013 and -1.

I want a output like the bellow

```
dt          |price  |Return
-------------------------------------
01-Jan-2013 |55.6   |0
-------------------------------------
02-Jan-2013 |50.22  |-0.09676259
-------------------------------------
03-Jan-2013 |52     |0.035444046
-------------------------------------
04-Jan-2013 |55.9   |0.075
-------------------------------------
05-Jan-2013 |60.6   |0.084078712
```

How Can I get the result whithin a single SQL Statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fairly straightforward:

```
select
   t1.dt,t1.price,
  (t1.price/t2.price)-1 as [return]
from
   #tmp t1
      left join
   #tmp t2
      on t1.dt = DATEADD(day,1,t2.dt)
```

Note that this currently returns `NULL` for the first row rather than `0`, but that could be fixed by wrapping the calculation in a `COALESCE(...,0)` if required. Note, also, that this assumes that there are values for every day. If that's not so, we need a more complex query.

---

If you need to allow for missing dates, you're going to have to pay a price for a significantly slower query:

```
select
   t1.dt,t1.price,
  (t1.price/t2.price)-1 as [return]
from
   #tmp t1
      left join
   #tmp t2
      on t2.dt < t1.dt
      left join
   #tmp t3
      on t3.dt < t1.dt and
         t2.dt < t3.dt
where
   t3.dt is null
```

Ignoring for the moment that all these rows are coming from the same table, what we're basically saying is to pair the `t1` rows with *any* `t2` rows which occur before the `t1` rows. We then try to find (via `t3`) any rows which occur *after* the `t2` rows, but still before the `t1` rows. Only if we cannot locate a `t3` row is the `t2` row the one we wanted - it's the latest possible previous row. Sorry if that sounds convoluted, always searching for a better way to explain this.

Comment: in  some dates it returns wrong value if the date is missing, you already mentioned here that these values are for everyday. Can I get that complex query where date is sequential but some dates are missing. Thanks.